# Are there any books on economy of the medieval England?

Tags: reference-request, history, economic-history, books, uk

I would like to learn more about how the medieval economy in the UK worked. Are there any economists that research medieval society in the UK? Are there some good books on this?

Comment: There is a relevant Wikipedia-entry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economy_of_England_in_the_Middle_Ages Maybe, you can find what you want in the references.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker thank you, but I was looking for some book recommendations. I know wikipedia has references but it is difficult to judge which are good